# Why can't you derive a HKDF key with with WebCrypto?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, webcrypto-api

I want to take a password and run it through PBKDF2 to create a master key. I then want to take that and run it through HKDF to create multiple keys. It seems as though `crypto.subtle.deriveKey` will not accept HKDF as a `derivedKeyAlgorithm`.

In other words I can't get something like this to work

```
const kd_algo = { name: "PBKDF2", hash: "SHA-256", salt: pbkdf2_salt, iterations: 100000 }
const master_key = await crypto.subtle.deriveKey(kd_algo, password, { name: "HKDF" }, false, ["deriveKey"])
```

but this will

```
const kd_algo = { name: "PBKDF2", hash: "SHA-256", salt: pbkdf2_salt, iterations: 1000000 }
const master_key_material = await crypto.subtle.deriveBits(kd_algo, password, 256)
const master_key = await crypto.subtle.importKey("raw", master_key_material, "HKDF", false, ["deriveKey"])
```

This makes no sense.

Comment: You can use PBKDF2 to derive multiple keys by using different salts.

Comment: @kelalaka Not a good idea, as an adversary probably only has to run PBKDF2 once, so you'd have additional work for no reason at all. Using PBKDF2 with SHA-512 and splitting the key afterwards makes more sense. Or using PBKDF2 instead of HKDF. But in both cases you'd still have an intermediate value, so it won't actually solve much.

Comment: JS crypto API's generally have been designed to make no sense if you ask me, I haven't seen any indication of a reasonable JS crypto API unfortunately.

Comment: Afaik `deriveKey` essentially does what happens in the 2. code snippet, i.e. passes the data from `deriveBits` (here created with PBKDF2) to `importKey` to derive a key (here with HKDF), [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/#SubtleCrypto-method-deriveKey). But apparently HKDF is not supported in step 2, because otherwise there would have to be an object for the `derivedKeyAlgorithm` parameter that is tailored to HKDF (analogous to e.g. `HmacKeyGenParams` or `AesKeyGenParams`), [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/deriveKey). You could file this as issue.

Comment: I also encountered this exact problem almost two years later, and have filed an issue against WebCrypto [here](https://github.com/w3c/webcrypto/issues/314).