# WebCrypto: How can one use `deriveKey` with a key which came from `deriveKey`?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, webcrypto-api

I would like to create a "master key" from a password using PBKDF2, and then create various application-specific keys using HKDF from that "master key". However, when I try to use `SubtleCrypto.deriveKey` with a usage of `deriveKey`, it throws an opaque error:

> Error: Data provided to an operation does not meet requirements

For the moment, I have worked around this by exporting the "master key" and then re-importing it with the appropriate key usage, but this requires marking my "super key" as exportable, which should not be necessary. Using `deriveBits` has the same issue.

I will accept an answer which either demonstrates how to use `SubtleCrypto.deriveKey` on a key itself created using `SubtleCrypto.deriveKey`, or else confirms that this is a flaw in the WebCrypto API and that what I am trying to do is not possible (ideally with a reference to the WebCrypto spec).

I'm sure there will be questions about why I want to do this:

- The goal is to have multiple applications be unlocked by a single password.
- If the key for any one of these applications is leaked, it should not impact the security of the other applications.
- Once a user has entered their password, the "master key" will be kept around for the next N minutes to allow multiple application-specific keys to be derived, but I don't want to keep around the original password for any length of time.

I have tried many possibilities for the `derivedKeyType` argument to `deriveKey`, but all seem to result in an error.

Comment: No, that (still) doesn't seem possible, see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65112015/9014097) and this [WebCrypto issue #314](https://github.com/w3c/webcrypto/issues/314).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for but unable to find...